# Extract face from image of face extracted ( resize face extracted )

Tags: python, opencv, haar-classifier

I'm trying to get the minimum possible size of a face extracted from an image, I mean, I would like to minimize the size of the drawn rectangle that detect the face.
For example:

**The input image:**

[image]

**The desired output:**

[image]

Source code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade =cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
img=cv2.imread('swaa.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3,5,maxSize=(150,150))
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite("imgg1.png",roi_color)
    cv2.imwrite("imggg1.png",roi_gray)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.imwrite("img1.png",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Image source: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322649666_Emotion_Recognition_from_Facial_Expressions_using_Hybrid_Feature_Descriptors

Update: using the solution posted, the results are shown below:

[image: Orginal code]

[image: After using the solution]

Answer (score 0):

Just use cv2.resize function. https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
H = 64
W = 64
face_cascade =cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
img=cv2.imread('swaa.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3,5,maxSize=(150,150))
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = cv2.resize(gray[y:y+h, x:x+w], (H, W))
    roi_color = cv2.resize(img[y:y+h, x:x+w], (H,W))
    cv2.imwrite("imgg1.png",roi_color)
    cv2.imwrite("imggg1.png",roi_gray)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.imwrite("img1.png",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The solution you have posted doesn't solve my problem, Indeed, the code that you've written, change only the size of the image but not the size of the rectangle drawn around the face.

Comment: your question is extremely unclear, put all the requirements clearly.

Comment: Still it's not clear. Maybe update with a list `what change do you need`? if possible with a sample input and output.

Comment: I have made another update. Take a look at the post.